# InnerException throws TypeLoadException TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.UriTemplate' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel,

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, .net-framework-version

I've tried to implement an azure functions but keep getting the following exception.

```
  "TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.UriTemplate' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
```

It seems that there's a few other who get the same exceptions. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3568

I've implemented my solution with .NETCore 3.0 and AzureFunctions with v2.0 and use WindowsAzure.ServiceBus v6.0.0, System.private.ServiceModel 4.6.0 and System.ServiceModel.Primitives 4.6.0.
As far as i can tell there shouldn't be problem with versions but at this point I'm not sure.

In the link there are quite a few workaround and I've tried them but with no result. In all of them I've changed the file structure to match mine. ( I know some of them are meant for other types of projects and so on but none the less it was worth a shot).

```
<Target Name="FixForDotnetWcfIssueBuild" BeforeTargets="PostBuildEvent"> <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutputPath)bin\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Private.ServiceModel.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)bin" /> </Target> 

<Target Name="FixForDotnetWcfIssuePublish" AfterTargets="AfterPublish"> <Copy SourceFiles="$(PublishDir)bin\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Private.ServiceModel.dll" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)bin" /> </Target>
```

So to me it seems that WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 6.0.0 isn't compatible with .NETCoreApp v3.0.

Hopefully someone knows something I don't and are willing to help and I've told enough to solve this puzzle.

Comment: Can you show the configuration of the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Function has two Versions. One is based on .NET Framework and another is based on .NET Core. From your description, seems you are using `.NET Core 3.0`, `Function v2.0`.

Your project use `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus v6.0.0`, but have you seen the instructions of this Nuget package?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/

It is based on .NET Framework.

if you using this package on the false technical stack, off course this exception will appear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I changed it and I can now run the function application. I still don't know how to run it locally but I'll just test it another way.

Comment: @LasseAndersen If my solution is helpful to you, can you mark it as the answer of the question? It will help others who meet the similar question.